# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException @Autowired - Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

Tags: spring, autowired

I've got two classes A and B.

```
@Component("abc")
public class A {
  @Autowired
  private B b123;
}

@Component("xyz")
public class B {

}
```

At application startup time (in tomcat) I get the below error:
BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private B A.b123; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xyz' is defined

If I change the 'xyz' to 'b123' ,still I get the same error (with b123 in place of xyz)

I'm bit puzzled why @Autowired is looking for a bean by name defined in @Component, and still not finding it!
If I remove the bean name from @Component in class B , then @Autowired looks for bean with name 'B', i.e. the class name!

[The classes are in different jars in different packages]

Debugging the spring code, I find that Spring first calculates the beanName to be injected as 'xyz', later on it searches for a bean 'xyz' which it does not find and throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException on line 687 of DefaultListableBeanFactory.java. 
This behavior is either due to a bug in spring or the app context(s) are really messed up in the application!

Comment: Try to use @Qualifier

Comment: @Qualifier is needed when there are ambiguous beans. In this case the bean is not found.

Comment: Is Spring configured to look for components in the package where `B` is located?

Comment: @Morfic Yes, spring is scanning and picking B.For autowiring b123, spring looks for bean of type B, then it calculates the bean name of the bean for injection as 'xyz', then searches for bean named 'xyz' and fails to find it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring tries to inject a bean with name 'xyz' into A.b123 . In your configuration there is nothing that could cause spring trying this.
Your code :

```
@Component("xyz")
public class B
```

is creating a bean with name 'xyz' but would not cause the given exception.

Comment: That's what seems to be happening as per my findings. The actual case is slightly more complex as B is parametrized B<P, Q> and a subtype 'xyz' needs to be injected.

Comment: @Prakash can you add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to illustrate the exact scenario? Also if you prefer to share the sources inline instead of sharing them via services such as github or similar, please include details about spring(boot?!) & any other required library versions

Comment: working intermittently on this issue. 
observations:
1. Different DefaultListableBeanFactory locating and searching the bean 'xyz'.
2. The issue not reproducible if I have simple classes. Issue only present for generic types
3. Even if I move the classes not found to the same jar, still issue is reproducible.

Looks like bug with generic type handling by spring.

Java 1.7, Spring 4.1.6, Spring batch 3.0.6, Spring batch admin 1.3.1